# Workaround: Report (CSV) -> SFTP -> Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio

I created a 'discover' report that my goal is send this data to a Data Extension. I tried to create an automation that the report goes to ftp like csv and after report run, this automation get the data and update a Data Extension.

But the Import Activity only get file insides the 'Import' folder and the Report files goes to 'Report' folder.

Someone know a workaround to how do this without work manually? In the case the report file go to 'Import' folder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add in the 'Report' FTP folder as a File Location in Admin.
[image]
[image]
[image]

From there you just change your import activity to reference this new location and then you should be able to use an automation to import it into a DE.

[image]